# Proving $\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{p}{n \log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n \log n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, exponential-function

If we define $b_{n}:=\dfrac{1}{n(\log n)^{p}},\:n \geq 2, p>0$, prove that
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{p}{n \log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n \log n}\right)$$

What I tried:
We have $$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{(n+1)\left(\log (n+1)\right)^{p}}{n(\log n)^{p}}$$
$\implies$
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\left(\frac{\log n+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log n}\right)^{p}$$

$\implies$
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log n}\right)^{p}$$
Using $(1+x)^p=1+px+...$

We get
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{p \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log n}+\cdots \cdot\right)$$
Now since $n \geq 2$, we have:
$$\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^{2}}+\cdots$$
Thus we get
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{\frac{p}{n}}{\log n}+..\right)$$
So we get
$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{p}{n \log n}+\frac{p}{n^{2} \log n}+\cdots$$
But could I not get the $o$ notation term ?

Comment: Can someone help with this question please